# create a child process

Tags: .net, asp.net, process

You can create a thread given a delegate to method, can I create a process in the same way?  I want to do that to be able to close the child process from task manager if something goes wrong.

I expect the answer is no and the only typical way is windows service.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "same way", you mean passing a delegate as an argument for a given process then no, this is not possible. You will have to create a new executable which would do some tasks based on command line parameters. Though, the general rule is to avoid process spawning as it's VERY expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this (C#):

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\test.exe");
proc.Start(procInfo);
```